# Is it possible to use boost::serialization with managed class?

Tags: visual-c++, boost, c++-cli, managed-c++, boost-serialization

We have a lot of native c++ classes that are serialized perfectly using **boost::serialization**.

Now we want to change some of their member fields to **property**, so we could use them in **PropertyGrids**. When we changed the class definiction to **ref class X**, we got a huge number of these compilation errors:

#1:
`error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'boost::archive::text_oarchive &boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator <<(T &)'    d:\someAddress\someFile.cpp    58`

#2:
`error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::_Smanip<_Arg> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'boost::archive::text_oarchive'    d:\someAddress\someFile.cpp    58`

We have a lot of tiny classes here, so it would be a pain to write a wrapper for each of them!

Here is the sample class we used:

```
ref class gps_position2
{
public:
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & seconds;
    }
public:
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(float s)
    {
        this->seconds = s;
    }

    property float seconds;
};
```

And here is the main test code:

```
int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("out.txt");

    gps_position2 g(24.567f);

    // save data to archive
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        // write class instance to archive
        oa << g;
    }
    // ................
    return 0;
}
```

Is it even possible to use **boost::serialization** with managed classes?

**Edit:**

If we change the class usage code to this:

```
    ...
    gps_position2^ g = gcnew gps_position2(24.567f);
    ...
```

then we get only 1 error:

`error C2027: use of undefined type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<x>'    D:\path\to\Boost\boostw\boost\archive\detail\check.hpp    60`

Comment: Does the problem still happen when the property is removed (but the class remains a ref class)?

Comment: Can you use .NET serialization instead?  C++ and c++-cli aren't the same language.  Though they can intermix to some extent, boost is for C++, not C++-cli.

Comment: @CiscolPPhone: Yes, it still remains. @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: No, we have to use boost:serialization in the main code (in native C++), this code is only a tool for the main program.

Comment: What version of boost? There may be a description in that line of check.hpp. You may also want to try your question at http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user.

Comment: Thanks doomdayx, but I've already asked it there and got no clear answer (only this comment: "Unknown if they can work with managed classes, but do know for sure that Managed C++ has a *LOT* of template issues and in general does not work with 'real' C++ code.") About the version: we use boost 1.42 here.

Comment: @Sayyid: Well my suggestion is the same of Merlyn... I would use .NET serialization classes. When programming on vc++ you can acess the core classes of .NET which let you access a lot of functionalities... boost library would be useless... I understand that probably your one is a porting issue and that you would like to recompile your existing program in vc++ but that is not so easy. vc++ is not the same as c++ they have different syntax, different way of managing inheritance and virtual tables... everything changes... it's like asking: can I convert my app in pascal?

Comment: I have been writing code in both C++ and C++ Cli for a long time in a big project. To my experiences, do not write any code involving `boost` namespace in C++ Cli projects. Especially `boost::serialization`.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but you might be able to make this work by implementing your own global overloads of `operator<<` and `operator>>`, taking managed class references, which serve as adapters to the Boost versions.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you don't want to wrap all your classes. However, instead of wrapping all your classes in C++/CLI, it might be worth developing an unmanaged C++ dll and exposing all the relevant functions. You can then use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyzhw3s8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to call your unmanaged dll from managed code (eg. C++/CLI). Not sure if this would be feasible.